# MVC: Repopulate filters form's fields without using Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

I need to repopulate a form of filters, in a View in which I can't use the Model for doing so (Already using Model to bring an IEnumerable of an object, in order to create a table).

How can I fill the filters inputs so the user doesn't have to by himself?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3.

Graphic example so it's clearer:

```
public ViewResult Consulta(string dominio, string cliente, DateTime?
desde, DateTime? hasta, int? estado, string origen, int? reclamoid)
{
    var reclamos = db.Reclamos.Where(/*Apply filters, etc*/);
    return View(reclamos.ToList());
}
```

As you can see, these are too many to just use a ViewBag for each filter, so I wonder if there is a way to do this the plural way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can pass a model in part of the ViewData, ViewBag or TempData. Move all of those properties to a FilterModel and pass the model as part of the ViewData

Comment: Any example of that? I mean, not sure what's the syntax for that solution.

Comment: @Umagon - The syntax?  You just create a wrapper model class that has all your filter properties.  Then you assign an instance of that class to ViewBag.Filters or something, then in your view use ViewBag.Filters.hasta or ViewBag.Filters.origen

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood the answer. It seems good, but I think I will use the answer above, in this case. Thanks to both, anyway!

Comment: That should go in as an answer, that's a fine way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mattytommo has one example of how to create a new complex model to do it but I have two other methods.

The first is to create a better defined complex model as this gives you a more defined model. It contains your filter and your results siloed.

```
 public class MyFilterModel
 {
     public string Dominio { get; set; } 
     public string Cliente { get; set; } 
     public DateTime? Desde { get; set; } 
     public int? Estado { get; set; } 
     public string Origen { get; set; } 
     public int? Reclamoid { get; set; }  
 }

 public class MyViewModel
 {
      public MyFilterModel Filters {get;set;}
      public IEnumerable<DataRow> Results {get;set;}
 }
```

The other option is keep your existing model but use the ViewBag or ViewData to pass the filter model:

```
 public class MyFilterModel
 {
     public string Dominio { get; set; } 
     public string Cliente { get; set; } 
     public DateTime? Desde { get; set; } 
     public int? Estado { get; set; } 
     public string Origen { get; set; } 
     public int? Reclamoid { get; set; }  
 }
```

In your controller

```
 public ViewResult Consulta(MyFilterModel filters)  
 {  
      ViewBag.Filters = filters;
     var reclamos = db.Reclamos.Where(/*Apply filters, etc*/);  
     return View(reclamos.ToList());  
 }
```

In your view

```
 @model MyViewModel
 @{
      MyFilterModel filters = ViewBag.Filters as MyFilterModel;
 }

 @Html.EditorFor(m => filters.Dominio)
```

Comment: Wow, this seems pretty neat. I liked the last, the most. I think I will use this instead, because maybe with this I also can solve other lots-a-filters views I need to make. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I know you said without using the model, but your reasoning was that your current model is an IEnumerable for a table. Why not just create a view model that has your current IEnumerable as a property and the rest of the properties that you need? Better practice than using the ViewBag.

Something like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<RowData> TableRows { get; set; } //your table rows
    public string Dominio { get; set; }
    public string Cliente { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Desde { get; set; }
    public int? Estado { get; set; }
    public string Origen { get; set; }
    public int? Reclamoid { get; set; } 
}
```

Then in your view declare your model as:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

Then you can do in the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Dominio)
//then editors for the rest of the model fields

//then you can populate your tablerows using Model.TableRows
```

Comment: This is preferred over the ViewBag approach mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will be easier and cleaner to implement.

Comment: No problem, just out of interest why did you revoke the acceptance of my answer? :)

Comment: I accepted the actual accepted answer; I used that approach instead. Applied to my case, that served me somewhat better. Anyway, thanks for answering.